# Why is <select>'s attribute 'value' can't be set?

Tags: javascript, html

I've searched the web but couldn't find the answer. I know that you can set its value by Javascript, so why can't you do it by html?

Comment: AFAIK, `select` don't have `value` attribute.

Comment: @RobG I think that holds the value of selected options `value` attribute. I hope OP understood now.

Comment: @Mr_Green—it's a little more complex than that. It's the value of the *first* selected option (there may be more than one for a multiple select) or the text content if there is no value attribute or the property hasn't been assigned a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no valid attribute 'value' for 'select' element.
see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

You can set any property to any DOM element via javascript, but it is not saying that the property has its valid counterpart in html.

edit:
better link here:
[**https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/select**](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/select)

Comment: Please do not reference w3schools, the W3C is the standards body responsible for [*HTML*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/Overview.html), though MDN is a useful reference too.

Comment: w3schools tends to have many inaccuracies. For `<select>` they start with `The <select> element is used to create a drop-down list.` but `select` itself does not imply that it needs to be a drop down list, the way a `select` is visualized depends on the browser, os and device type. In this particular case this is just a minor flaw, but those inaccuracies are through out the whole page, leading to many misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0):

> … I know that you can set its value by Javascript

Only by setting an option as selected. The *value* property of select elements is read–only (see [*HTML5 §4.10.7 The select element*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-select-element)).

Answer (score 0):

Because <select>s can be multivalued

Answer (score 0):

If you want do it with html,that is `<option>`'s job.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the <kbd>[SELECT](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/select.html)</kbd> element!

**NOTE:** Checkout [W3Fools](http://www.w3fools.com/) before going to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)!

```html
<select>
  <option value="lorem">Lorem</option>
  <option value="ipsum">ipsum</option>
  <option value="dolor">dolor</option>
  <option value="sit">sit</option>
  <option value="amet">amet.</option>
</select>
```

The <kbd>[SELECT](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/select.html)</kbd> element only accepts following attributes

- autofocus
- disabled
- form
- multiple
- name
- required
- size
- id
- class

If you want to add a value you would have to do it to an <kbd>option</kbd> of the <kbd>select</kbd> element. [[fiddle]](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#7205dc9e8d6b684b3ddd2ca8477e5cef)